# How to properly access the data of a unsigne char pointer in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to write a series of classes that will simulate some hardaware behaviour. To properly interface with the rest of the program my class needs to use `unsigned char * bb` as an input. Since I've never worked with this particular type before I created the following test program just to see how to access/interpret the data:

```
// This will be the test bench
int main() {

  unsigned char * bytebuffer = new unsigned char[100];
  bytebuffer = (unsigned char *) 548;
  InstructionDeco deco(bytebuffer);
  return 0;
}
```

And the constructor has:

```
InstructionDeco::InstructionDeco(unsigned char *bb){
  cout << "Hola" << endl;
  if (bb){
    cout << "Not NULL" << endl;
  }
  else{
    cout << "Si es NULL" << endl;
  }
  cout << "El BB es " << bb << endl;
}
```

This tells me that the pointer is Not NULL, but no matter how I change the line

> bb << endl

To bb[0] or *bb or *bb[0] I allways get a segmetation fault at that line. I'm thinking that I don't know how to properly access the data.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The line `bytebuffer = (unsigned char *) 548;` looks scary to me.

Comment: The problem is, your buffer is 100 bytes long and exists anywhere in the working memory-space of your PC. It may be that there is 200mb of memory before it, it may be that there is 4.6gb (both entirely arbitrary) Your buffer variable will hold the address of the first byte of this 100 byte buffer - lets assume it starts at 2gb, so in that case it will hold the value 0x80000000 . When you set bytebuffer to hold the value 548, you're saying that 548 bytes of memory exist before your buffer - you definitely dont own that area any more than you have the right to put stuff on your neighbors lawn!

Comment: This makes sense. That line I got from an stackoverflow answer. But I might have misinterpreted the nature of the question. How do I initialize the buffer with some data then?

Comment: Great!! I just added data with a for cycle and this worked!!! Thank you!!

Comment: @aarelovich - you're welcome (if you were thanking me, that is) and in any case, glad to hear you've got a clearer understanding now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to dereference a pointer to address 548, which is an invalid address.

Comment: Now that I found the problem I see you were correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> unsigned char * bytebuffer = new unsigned char[100];
>
> bytebuffer = (unsigned char *) 548;

You asked to allocate 100 bytes and the pointer of that area was put in `bytebuffer` - Line 1.

But then you override (why???) the address of the allocated area and instead of that address you put 548 - Line 2 (causing memory leak because now you lost the pointer to the allocated area and won't be able to release it later).

When you try to access the `bb` by `*bb` or `bb[0]` you actually try to access the data at address 548. Most likely that this address doesn't belong to your process so you get a segmentation fault.

Comment: I thought I was initializing the bytebuffer with the value 548. Did not realize that I was overriding the POINTER value. Thank you.

Comment: @aarelovich You need to access it by `bytebuffer[x] = y;` Note that 0<=x<100 and y<256 since the pointer is to `unsigned char` which is one byte. If you assign to it 548 (which is 0x224) the compiler will leave only 8 bytes ==> 0x24. it you want to put a value which is greater than 1 byte you need to cast the pointer to other pointer type, like `uint16_t`: `((uint16_t*)bytebuffer)[0] = 548;` but in this case you are using 2 bytes. bytebuffer [0] and bytebuffer [1] will become initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is in `bytebuffer = (unsigned char *) 548;` line. You assign a pointer a 548 value. This isn't allocated memory, that's why you get segfault.